# Error while running a test CI pipeline on Gitlab CE selfhosted

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I have installed a self hosted Gitlab CE and tried to run a test CI pipeline and getting following error. Will you be able to shed some light on this? Many thanks

I need help to resolve this.

Comment: This is the error... 
/usr/bin/bash: line 118: python: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: I have resolved this issue by adding following image: python:3.9